# Composite Moduli

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

The following passage can be found in Burton's Elementary Number Theory:

"Assume that $a$ is odd. Because the square of any odd integer
is congruent to 1 modulo 8, we see that for the congruence $x^2 \equiv a \pmod {2^n},$ where $n\geq 3,$ to be
solvable $a$ must be of the form $8k + 1.$"

The only thing I know here is that the square of any odd integer
is congruent to 1 modulo 8. Using this, how to show the last part?

Answer (score 1):

Consider any solution, where $x^2 = a + j 2^n$ for some integer $j$; $a$ is odd, so $x^2$ is odd, so $x$ is odd.  Thus $a + j 2^n$ is the square of an odd integer, and is congruent to $1$ mod $8$.  But $2^n$ is also divisible by $8$ since $n \ge 3$, so $a$ is congruent to $1$ mod $8$.

Comment: So $a+j2^n\equiv 1\pmod 8$. Note that $j2^n\equiv 0\pmod 8$ because $8\mid 2^n$ for $n\geq 3$. Thus, $a\equiv 1\pmod 8.$ Got it thank you!